# PHP loop for array on the basis of index numbers

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

I am getting an array as an output from Order tracking api, its values vary in even numbers like sometimes it contains 2 values, sometimes it contains 4, sometimes 6, or 8.

Forexample

```
$array = array(time1,status1);
```

and sometimes

```
$array = array(time1,status1,time2,status2);
```

Or

```
$array = array(time1,status1,time2,status2,time3,status3);
```

So what I am doing, I have  a timeline to show order status.
Here is its code

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>time</h2>
      <p>status</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>time</h2>
      <p>status</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want is to create a loop in php to show time (odd index number values) in h2 tag and status (even index numbers) in p tag

The number of values in array may vary so I want a loop to create timeline for each time and its corresponding status.

Comment: You should instead change the way the API outputs the data if possible. That format makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you'd be able to configure the API to send out something in a `'key' => 'value'` type pair, especially something as "key : value" related as "time : status". Unfortunately, I'm *well aware* that depending on the API provider, this may not be possible.

So, provided that you *can't* change the API's response at all, and you always just get an array that's `2n` long, you can simply use a [`for()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop or [`while`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop (or any other control structure, really) to loop through the array and output the information you need with one of the [Increment Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) available. You could also make use of something from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501422/reorganizing-an-array-odd-entries-as-key-even-entries-as-value) to reorganize your array into `key:value` pairs, but that *may* be overkill for this.

Here's a simple example using a simple `while` loop:

```php
// Sample API Response (unsure of format, so Unix Timestamp + Text Status)
$api_response = array(
    1605552893, 'Processing',
    1605451893, 'Pending',
    1605350893, 'Complete',
    1605250893, 'Complete',
    1605150893, 'Complete',
    1605050893, 'Complete'
);

// Define some starting variables
$i = 0;                    // Start a counter at 0
$n = count($api_response); // Store length as a variable
$side = 'left';            // Set the first directional side

// Proceed to loop through the response
while( $i < $n ){
    /**
     * This is the iterable HTML block
     *
     * We use the Post-Increment operator ($i++) to
     * get the current index [0] and then bump it up
     * to [1] automatically. This gives us [0][1] in
     * the first iteration, [2][3] in the second, etc
     */
    printf( '<div class="content %s">
        <h2>%s</h2>
        <p>%s</p>
    </div>', $side, date('M jS, D', $api_response[$i++]), $api_response[$i++]);

    // Set side to the opposite of current side
    if( $i % 2 === 0 )
        $side = ($side=='left') ? 'right' : 'left';
}
```

The output of which would be:

```html
<div class="content left">
    <h2>Nov 16th, Mon</h2>
    <p>Processing</p>
</div>
<div class="content right">
    <h2>Nov 15th, Sun</h2>
    <p>Pending</p>
</div>
<div class="content left">
    <h2>Nov 14th, Sat</h2>
    <p>Complete</p>
</div>
<!-- … etc … -->
```

As you can see [at this sandbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb3b70d83389c767168289d24839ace4d3999b08) (click on the <kbd>Execute Code</kbd> button to see the output.

Two final things:

• You may want to consider using an HTML/CSS structure that doesn't rely on `left` and `right` CSS classes like [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but I put in a simple [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to switch between the two for you for now.

• In that `while` loop, you may want to validate what type of data each value of `$api_response[$i]` is, to make sure that you're getting a time string in your expected format, and status in your expected format. You can use [`continue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to skip the iteration if something is wrong (like you got two time strings in a row or something).